# Copiar una palabra justo al lado de otra

Tags: python, python-2.7

Estoy empezando con *python* y estoy intentando hacer un *script* que coja un archivo `txt` con una lista de palabras en vertical y que copie la misma palabra al lado de esta de manera automática, sería algo así.

diccionario.txt:

```
casa123
perro454
gato783
raton12
```

y quiero conseguir esto:

```
casa123casa123
perro454perro454
gato783gato783
raton123raton123
```

Lo que tengo del *script* es esto, y no consigo que se me muestre como quiero. Se que es simple pero siempre cuesta empezar. Espero que puedan ayudarme y gracias.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python  

dic = open("/media/particion/dic.txt", "r+") for linea in dic:  
      dic2 = open("/media/particion/dic2.txt", "a")  
      s1 = linea + linea  
      dic2.write(s1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sería algo así:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

dic = open("/media/particion/dic.txt","r")
dic2 = open("/media/particion/dic2.txt", "w")
lineas= [linea+linea for linea in dic]

for texto in lineas:
    dic2.write("%s\n" % texto)

dic.close()
dic2.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta de @David es correctísima y la he votado positiva ya que es una respuesta canónica y la evidente para resolver el problema en cuestión. La mia es solo por divertimento y por mostrar una solución más corta usando [*context managers*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers) disponibles en [Python desde Python 2.5 (no es algo nuevo)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/):

```
with open('/media/particion/dic.txt') as a, open('/media/particion/dic2.txt', 'w') as b:
    [b.write(line.replace('\n','')+line) for line in a]
```

Un *context manager* en Python no es más que un [objeto que se encarga de hacer determinado trabajo para tí](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#context-manager-types) al que le tienes que definir los métodos mágicos `__enter__` y `__exit__` para que sepa lo que hacer.

Además, he usado una *list comprehension* para escribir los datos en el nuevo fichero, se podrían usar otras opciones pero suelo abusar de las *list comprehensions* :-P

**Actualización**: Como bien indica @ChemaCortes es un comentario más abajo, usando una *list comprehension* almacenas en memoria mucha información que quizá no sea relevante y se podrían usar generadores y [deque](/questions/tagged/deque) como alternativa para evitar el inconveniente del uso de memoria.

Comment: Casi se podría decir que fueron diseñadas para abusarse

Comment: No estoy muy de acuerdo en usar *list comprehesions* para estas cosas. Si el fichero tuviera 1000000 líneas estarías gastando memoria en crear una lista de igual número de elementos que no ibas a utilizar para nada. Mejor usar un bucle for en este caso, pero si quieres ser original usa mejor una *"expresión generadora"* y recórrela con [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.deque) para gastarla: `deque(b.write(line[:-1]+line) for line in a, maxlen=1)`

Comment: Uno nunca deja de aprender con el maestro @ChemaCortes. He actualizado la respuesta para enlazar tu comentario.